# 'pmd.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: pmd

I want to install PMD errors in my PC I did all the steps but getting this error

> 'pmd.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

how to override it.

Comment: You don't need to _"override"_ anything. You just need to [follow the Quickstart instructions on the home page for PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) for your particular operating system. Update your question with full details of _exactly what you did_ to install PMD. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on improving your question.

Comment: pmd.bat is probably not on the PATH. See the 3rd step from the [Quickstart instruction](https://pmd.github.io):

3. Add folder C:\pmd-bin-6.54.0\bin to PATH, either
    * Permanently: Using System Properties dialog > Environment variables > Append to PATH variable
    * Temporarily, at command line: SET PATH=C:\pmd-bin-6.54.0\bin;%PATH%

This depends however, where you extracted the zip archive.